# ARMeshAnchor – SceneKit SCNView Renderer EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

Im converting the ARMeshAnchor data to mesh using SCNGeometrySource which it works fine but sometimes 3/10 I will get a bad_access from SceneKit renderer.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It occurs because `ARMeshAnchors` constantly update their data as ARKit refines its understanding of the real world. All `ARMeshAnchors` are dynamic anchors. However their mesh's subsequent changes are not intended to reflect in real time.

If you want to duplicate your ARMeshAnchors collection use the following code:

```
var anchorsArray = [ARMeshAnchor]()
    
let frame = arView.session.currentFrame
    
let meshAnchors = frame?.anchors.compactMap { $0 as? ARMeshAnchor }
    
anchorsArray += meshAnchors!
```

Every `ARMeshAnchor` is connected with primitive geometry data that's stored in `MTLBuffer`:

```
anchorsArray[0].geometry.faces.buffer
anchorsArray[0].geometry.vertices.buffer
anchorsArray[0].geometry.normals.buffer
anchorsArray[0].geometry.classification?.buffer
```

Comment: How do I make a deep copy/clone of ARMeshAnchor data?